# Path vs parametrized curve

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves

A parametrized curve is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, while a path need a (parameterized) curve along with a particular velocity. Moreover, along the same curve, points may travel with different velocity means a path may have different parametric curve representation.

Whether the above explanation is correct or need further understanding and intuition?

Comment: Your intuition is correct.

Comment: Continuous, not piecewise continuous.

Comment: @TonyK Corrected.